# Beginner - Web scraping - Download data

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to download this data https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2004/index.html

So far, I able to get the links from tag p and those are each month links, but challenge is that under those each link their are 31 files (for each day), which I tried several methods from stack to get h2 headings, and

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as urllib2

url = "https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2000/index.html"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
headings = soup.findAll('h2');


req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
print("The href links are :")

print (headings)

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
   print(link.get('href')) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
links_with_text = []
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True): 
    if a.text: 
        links_with_text.append(a['href'])

links_with_text = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True) if a.text]
links_with_text
```

and here is their output (only pasting last output)

```
['https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2000/index.html',
 'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2000/index.html#December',
 'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2000/index.html#November',
 'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2000/index.html#October',
 'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2000/index.html#September',
 'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2000/index.html#August',
 'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2000/index.html#July',
 'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2000/index.html#June',
 'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2000/index.html#May',
 'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2000/index.html#April',
 'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2000/index.html#March',
 'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2000/index.html#February',
 'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2000/index.html#January'
```

My question is that these are h2 tag headings and further I need the links from each of h2 tag, which are stored under each a tag.
Though above program gives me all links which does have those links, but if I could get them in organized way or any other way, which can be more easy to store data direct from html sites, will be great. I will appreciate any help. Thank. you!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to get the file names? The tables with real data seem to exist at URLs of this pattern: https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2004/20040528ps.html. You could pretty easily craft those URLs manually, since the only thing changing in the filename is the year/month/day.

Comment: @drnugent yes, that is the reason. Then each day has similar files, that will make the file itself too large with each url. Is there any way, I can automate the downloading, because data we need from few other years as well.

Comment: Yes, you can create a loop for all days from the start of the dataset until the end of the dataset, use that year/month/day to generate a filename of the given format, and then run  requests.get() on that URL.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Find All `h2` tag and loop over it now if you see `h2` tag has no data so we have to find next tag for that `find_next` method is used
>    on `p` tag
> 2. Now we have to find all `a` tag so we will use `find_all` method i have done this in one line of code it will return list of links
> 3. Now we will loop over it and extract only `href` part but there is a cath `href` is not correct it contains `20001231ps.html` like that
>    but we  need `20041231ps.html` like that so thats why i have done that
>    process of replacing and appending string
> 4. I have used `dict1` where it will append key as month and value as list of links so it will be easy to extract.

Code:

```
months=soup.find_all("h2")
dict1={}
main_url="https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2004"
for month in months:
    dict1[month.text]=[main_url+"/"+link['href'].replace("2000","2004") for link in month.find_next("p").find_all("a")]
```

Output:

```
{'December': ['https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2004/20041231ps.html',
  'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2004/20041230ps.html',
  'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2004/20041229ps.html',
  'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2004/20041228ps.html',
  'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2004/20041227ps.html',
  'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2004/20041226ps.html',
  'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2004/20041225ps.html',
  'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2004/20041224ps.html',
.....
]}
```

Comment: that is what I was looking for, thank you! that helps a lot! @bhavya-parikh

Comment: You can upvote or accept as answer if possible!!

Comment: I was trying, but it's not allowing me, I was not that active here. When I will have points, I will definitely upvote by myself. Thank you!

Comment: Am I missing something, its not giving me same input how did you called only December ?

Comment: it will return all months with its day wise links  i have just given you sample output

Comment: Yes, it worked! Appreciate it!

Comment: I was able to get the data, but now I am getting another issue while accessing, I can only able to pull information from the first reactor. Is there any other way, we can pull all reactor's information, either individually or together?